# Passing variable to URI filepath

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, file-path, uri

I want to load CSV file to QGIS. It works if I use the strings below:

```
uri ="file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Alex working/Tracks//Track.csv?delimiter={}&crs=epsg:25831&xField={}&yField={}".format(",", "Easting", "Northing")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "layer name you like", "delimitedtext")
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
```

But if I pass Filepath and name of the file to variable, the file fails to load.

```
import os
from qgis.core import (QgsVectorLayer)
Path="C:/Users/User/Desktop/Alex working/Tracks"
name="Track.csv"
uri ="file:///Path/name?delimiter={}&crs=epsg:25831&xField={}&yField={}".format(",", "Easting", "Northing")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "layer name you like", "delimitedtext")
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
```

What am I missing?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 6):

in your `uri` variable, `Path/name` is a literal string, not the variables `Path` and `name`.

Try:

```
uri ="file:///{}/{}?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:25831&xField=Easting&yField=Northing".format(Path, name)
```

Or using "`f''` strings"

```
uri =f"file:///{Path}/{name}?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:25831&xField=Easting&yField=Northing"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use this structure:

```
uri ="file:///" + Path + "/" + name + "?delimiter=,&crs=epsg:25831&xField=Easting&yField=Northing"
```